# Do elected attorneys general and prosecutors in the U.S. sue companies more frequently when re-elections are upcoming?

Tags: united-states, judiciary

I get the sense that this is true from anecdotal examples, as attorneys general (especially those with higher political ambitions) try to win future votes by being “tough on corporations”.

But I don’t have any data to formally examine this. If there is any study that sheds light on this, please share.

Comment: One problem is that elections are always upcoming. Do you have a time frame in mind?

Comment: @user6726 I agree, but if someone is elected to a four year term, the first two years should be relatively “worry free”... I would imagine that person will be more eager to “re-establish himself” towards the end of the term when re-election is more imminent.

Comment: Are you thinking about the US specifically (based on the term 'attorneys general')? I assume you're thinking about a relationship between the prosecutor and the election as well? So the election would be in the same locale as the cases? It's probably to extensive to answer based on data alone, but I think it could be answered if someone has studied this already (so there is some research for answerers to refer to).

Comment: @JJJ indeed, I'm thinking of the US specifically. And yes, I have in mind the prosecutor as well.

Comment: Not enough for an answer, but [this review by the Brennan Center](https://www.brennancenter.org/sites/default/files/publications/How_Judicial_Elections_Impact_Criminal_Cases.pdf) could be relevant.

Comment: @JJJ This is extremely helpful. I hope someone have done similar studies on lawsuits against companies. However, since most major lawsuits on companies are done in federal courts, would state judges/prosecutors still matter much?

Comment: In don't think that there is good enough data to establish it one way or the other, and there are also sorts of potential confounds.